# Narrowing a union of array types using Array.every

Tags: arrays, typescript, narrowing

I have a variable with a type that is a union of different array types. I want to narrow its type to a single member of that union, so I can run the appropriate code over it for each type. Using [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) seems like the right approach here, but when I try this TypeScript complains that "This expression is not callable." along with an explanation that I don't understand.

Here is my minimum reproducible example:

```
const isNumber = (val: unknown): val is number => typeof val === 'number';

const unionArr: string[] | number[] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

if (unionArr.every(isNumber)) { // <- Error
  unionArr;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwLYCMCmAnGBeGACgDcBDAGwC4ZkwBrMEAdzAEpqzz4IYw0tceAHwwoATwAOmEADMYnfHgIByPhhzKA3AFgAUHtCRYtOOACC2bNWjY4YAOYBtALowAPr344X+GAFlSKAALADpsUjAAExBUQlYYEQAGEIBWGAB+GEcARgAaGAAmfIBmfIAWfJTXakdlbOV85QKGmGViluUyjpTlZx19XTg5QhNzSxDMYhwxQgQUdWxWeIBvGAB6NZgAHgBaGABRSxBsPRgaMFMwC2x+gF8gA)

Here is the error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type
    '{
      <S extends string>(predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): this is S[];
      (predicate: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;
    } | {
      ...;
    }'
  has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

This isn't preventing me from continuing. I've found that using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to recast my array to `unknown[]` before I narrow its type, as I would do if I were writing an `isNumberArray` custom type guard, removes the error without compromising type safety.

I've also found that recasting my `string[] | number[]` array to `(string | number)[]` removes the error.

However, the type of the array doesn't seem to be narrowed correctly, so I would need to use an additional `as number[]` after the check:

```
const isNumber = (val: unknown): val is number => typeof val === 'number';

const unionArr: string[] | number[] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

if ((unionArr as unknown[]).every(isNumber)) { // <- No error
  unionArr; // <- Incorrectly typed as string[] | number[]
}

if ((unionArr as (string | number)[]).every(isNumber)) { // <- No error
  unionArr; // <- Incrrectly typed as string[] | number[]
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwLYCMCmAnGBeGACgDcBDAGwC4ZkwBrMEAdzAEpqzz4IYw0tceAHwwoATwAOmEADMYnfHgIByPhhzKA3AFgAUHtCRYtOOACC2bNWjY4YAOYBtALowAPr344X+GAFlSKAALADpsUjAAExBUQlYYEQAGEIBWGAB+GEcARgAaGAAmfIBmfIAWfJTXakdlbOV85QKGmGViluUyjpTlZx19XTg5QkITc0sYUh5aBmYwF1YQzGIcMUIEFHVsVniAbxgAegOYAB4AWhhEEBgcbBBsPRgaMFMwC2xNQ+PzmABJMFAlkwwCg5DEokkmEikx4NjsTlcHjUAhcegAvno9EMiKMXuNcFMiHCHO5PFtWAslitsGsNl5tnsvqcLlcbpZ7o9nq93p8jsy-gCgSCwRCpNDCcSEaTkd5nOigA)

I tried a comparison with a non-array union as well, though of course in this case I was just using the custom type guard directly instead of using it with `Array.every`. In that case, there was also no error and the type was narrowed correctly:

```
const isNumber = (val: unknown): val is number => typeof val === 'number';

const union: string | number = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : '1';

if (isNumber(union)) {
  union; // <- Correctly typed as number
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwLYCMCmAnGBeGACgDcBDAGwC4ZkwBrMEAdzAEpqzz4IYw0tceAHwwoATwAOmEADMYnfHgIByPhhzKA3AFgAUHtCRYtOOGrRscMAHMYAH178c+GAFlSUABYA6bKTAAJiCohKwwIgAM3gCsMAD8MACMMNTKiVp6enByhAgo6tiEJuCsYQDeejA0YKZgmjAA9A0wADwAtDAAwiDY2JjAUORiopKYATCkPGoCegC+ekA)

Because I have that safe type assertion workaround, I can continue without needing to understand this. But I'm still very confused as to why that error appears in the first place, given I am trying to narrow a union of types to a single member of that union.

I'm guessing this is something to do with how `Array.every` has been typed by TypeScript, and there's probably nothing I can do aside from the workaround I'm already using. But it's hard to be sure of that when I don't really understand what's going wrong. Is there something I could do differently here, or is the `as unknown[]` type assertion I've used the correct or best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a simpler example:

```
type StringOrNumberFn = (a: string | number) => void
type NumberOrBoolFn = (a: number | boolean) => void
declare const justNumber: StringOrNumberFn | NumberOrBoolFn

// works
justNumber(123) 

// errors
justNumber('asd')
justNumber(true)
```

When you have a union of functions that you try to invoke, you are actually calling a function that is the *intersection* of those members. If you don't know which function it is, then you may only call that function in ways that *both* functions support. In this case, both functions can take a `number`, so that's all that's allowed.

And if the intersection of those functions would have incompatible arguments, then the function cannot be called. So let's model that:

```
type StringFn = (a: string) => void
type NumberFn = (a: number) => void
declare const fnUnion: StringFn | NumberFn

fnUnion(123)    // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
fnUnion('asdf') // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

This is closer to your problem.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZTAJwJYDsDmB5ZA5AVwFsAjGZAMXTgF44AKAQwC44BnFDTOAHznWJlkASloA+OADcA9qgAmoSLDiFS5XACFp0gDZVaDFv0HlecEtp0xG6UTQkz5oOTADGOxsnivp6DnAArAg5VIVYkNCxcUPJ9PhjkTUsqUFAAejS4AHdpZABrNlAgkJNkegBGACYAZlFUkAy4cmRcwpBisAT6AHJGNjlu4SLgztL6FAIYIZB6pXgIrn06JlYOSMw7B1kFcGh4BKXDVgE1EXEpbec3Dy84Hz8wOAAzdABVdFRfcM4sOJVSlIzBqZZqtUAvd6fdAVGrTCEfXw9PpyJ6DIA)

---

A string array's `every` and a number array's `every` are typed to receive different parameters.

```
(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) // string[] every() args
(value: number, index: number, array: number[]) // number[] every() args
```

Which is essentially the same problem as above.

---

So I don't think there's a way that the compiler will be okay with calling the `every` method on this union.

Instead, I'd probably write a type assertion for the whole array and loop over it manually.

```
const isNumberArray = (array: unknown[]): array is number[] => {
  for (const value of array) {
    if (typeof value !== 'number') return false
  }

  return true
}

declare const unionArr: string[] | number[]

if (isNumberArray(unionArr)) {
  Math.round(unionArr[0]); // works
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwLYCMCmAnAgt7AQwE8YBeGACkIJIC4ZkwBrMEAdzAG0BdASgY0ipBDDBos2XuQB8MAN4BYAFAwYAMxDYqoSLABuhADbJMMEOphCSfBSrVq4lylGIAHTBZiGTZgIRkFADk4hg4QbbYmFDI2GAaxhCY9jAAviopUTFxMFDYpirpyioAJpjARjRmutCMYHDg+NgM0NhwYADm0gA+YhI4vBnKTlQIKGF4tMSUTA1gTXy2SqowALKEUAAWAHTYIEwlM-WNBFwADPwA3DAA9Dcw7FrMEIVAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Update July 2023

TypeScript 5.2, which is [currently in beta](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/), includes a feature that specifically changes how TypeScript behaves when you attempt to call a function with a union type in the specific case that the function is an array method, like the one I asked about in this question.

This section of the 5.2 beta announcement has more information: [Easier Method Usage for Unions of Arrays](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/#easier-method-usage-for-unions-of-arrays)