# React Query UseQueryResult type narrowing

Tags: typescript, casting, react-query

I'm using a list of queries with react-query to fetch "dependencies" and I want all the dependencies to load before rendering my component. I get the success state by checking all the deps as array and then act on it:

```
function DepsLoader() {
    const q1 = useQuery()
    const q2 = useQuery()
    const q3 = useQuery()
    const q4 = useQuery()

    const deps = [q1, q2, q3, q4]
    const allDone = deps.every(dep => dep.isSuccess)

    if (!allDone) return <Loading />

    return <Component q1={q1.data} q2={q2.data} q3={q3.data} q4={q4.data} />
}
```

In JS land, this works just fine. However, if I want to do the same in TS, I get an obvious error, that `q1.data` is `Data | undefined` because it is. Normally, one is supposed to narrow it down by first checking for `q1.isSuccess` directly, but in case of my list of dependencies, I don't want to do it manually (in real component, the list can be up to 9 queries atm).

I can as well cast it using `q1={q1.data as Q1Type}` but it's not ergonomic.

Is there any way to make TS recognise the fact that in reality all the queries are in success state and I have narrowed it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to perform type narrowing with a user defined type guard when executing `.every`, because TypeScript doesn't know that without it.

Here is a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ4A0c2ueA8gEYZQBuuASuqsgDYxEn6XV1QDKyAMaCmqRszZwAvnABmUCCDgByKOgCGgmAFoAjjnzKAsAChTgiADtU8YKgHDR41vAC8cABTqoUdXgBccGrqACZWLHjEBuRUuLzObAA8lsggFLgAfADaALoAlIHevpF2UaTccbgOIqhiTC7JqelQ2TlwrhmIpnBB6DDIUJZwRX4AdOi8eB4h6GDtnTNgo3bVonmmUqamssiWWsBWcADCipCW6JYwHmAKYKiBSLoAjIEpabhEugBMr0240nkuiYemp%20oM4CkWCwNlsTDs9jADkMACKzVAAGQgoVwHkBCG6cAs1ngz3aKAwnCmygA1ug8MoiLj5nAAAoKEB2dCjNSoCAsOgeACseXWwMJVhscG%20ZLQWGiHhpdIZnkBHVZ7M53KYfIFXwAzCLYT0iZLFqgyVlnp8vjkjXBgLJPCshDU6hIrmaRUCeiC%20gMhidwFYLldHi84GasgAGHKjELqGDqa2BSNPWPxxMAgk9AD0OZ9BcLRcLAD0APwEzZmMWg-0qFhYkLASwAc1G7eMJikQA) showing the gist of it, based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71012370/narrowing-a-union-of-array-types-using-array-every).

Comment: Thank you. The biggest gotcha is that I then have to pass the data as `deps[index].data` instead of using the original `qX.data` so that TS can track it. That made me try it with an Object instead of Array, but no luck there, so I'll stick with the Array for now. https://shorturl.at/iltNS (link to playground shortened to fit a comment).

Comment: Oh, and if somebody needs to hear it, the other issue is that it doesn't really work with different types. In this example, both query results are a `number`, if one was number and the other one was a string, it would make them both `number | string` after the `.every`, so I guess it still needs the casting for most cases.